# Which framework (Jquery, Dojo, Raphael) is better for implementing SVG on an Educative Video Game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, svg

I'm about to begin the development of an educative video game. I've decided to do it in a way that i could easily packed for Web, Mobiles and, maybe, Standalone versions.

I don't want to use Flash. So I'm convinced (I'll listen advices anyway) of using JavaScript and SVG.

I've being doing lots of research on this subject but I'm having a hard time putting the pieces together. I know that Raphaels seems to be simple and straightforward and Jquery and Dojo are maybe more complex but more powerful. It is possible to combine the difference frameworks? I don't mind complexity, i want to have the less amount of limitations as possible

I need the framework covers the following points:

- Handle highly interactive interfaces
- Could write a reusable code (I want to make different versions with the same skeleton)
- Enough documentation
- Could be extended to interact with social networks
- Could generate statistics associated to the events
- Compatibility with other frameworks

I also want to know if its advisable to mix different frameworks.

I'm open to all kinds of recommendations. I'm starting to learn Python also, so i would be nice to have an expert opinion on whether its advisable or not to use JavaScript with SVG or if it's worth it to used a more complex language on this purposes.

Thanks!!

EDIT

Until now I've decide not to use Jquery. Since I need a reusable code, I'm going to take advantage of the OOP features of JavaScript, and it seems that mootools is a lot better doing this (http://jqueryvsmootools.com/index.html). For manage SVG I'm going to try with Raphael. Any experince on using those frameworks side by side?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections to Kristiono Setyadi! I'm learning english so it's really useful for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope I do not turn you off from asking questions on websites, but in my personal opinion this question is not a good fit for this site. See [this FAQ topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Your question asks for opinion (which is **better**), not facts. You may wish to try [the chat system](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for discussion on which people think would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to give the chat a try. But i've seen several questions like this one, with good feedback on this site. And i'm not asking about a subjective opinion, i need that someone with enough experience on the subject give me some orientation on wich direction i need to follow. I'm going to use the chat though, and hope for the best!

See you!!

Comment: Oh, I need 20 reputation to use the chat. So i have to wait!!

Comment: @phrogz: His question is not *that* off topic though. He at least listed a list of priorities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest you to decide right away which platform you would use. I did couple projects while ago using JavaScript for game and there are several options.

1. SVG
2. HTMLCanvas
3. Flash
4. WebGL

You will need JavaScript framework with which you can easily switch between those option but not to change code dramatically. I'm suggesting [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js)

Before you download it, you can read some articles about it, for instance [this one](http://drawlogic.com/2010/04/25/three-js-javascript-3d-engine-with-canvas-and-svg-renderers/)

Believe me, if you want re-usability for this type of application forget for jQuery, tho it could be used for UI purposes

--- EDIT ---

I just remembered of another framework [The RenderEngine](http://therenderengine.blogspot.com/) source code is in [github](https://github.com/bfattori/TheRenderEngine)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the Data. I'm going to check this out and see wath happens. I'm not conssidering Flash (i don't want propietary lenguages and i find it to hermetic) or Canvas (wich i think is more suitable for other purposes). Though, i'm going to read about Three and WebGL, I never heared of them.

Answer (score 2):

Wow loads of questions
It's not a good idea to mix a load of Libraries though because you will end up with a fat js library footprint
I considered a few associated technologies but only one for me fits the bill

Maybe you will find other answers here
http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalraphael.php

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I think you have a point with the footprint. The link seems to be interesting, I let you know if works for me.

Answer (score 1):

SVG support under Android is complicated.  I was looking into this recently, and found that Android versions < 3.0 do not support SVG in the default WebKit: [Android Issue 1376](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1376), [Android Issue 4695](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4695)

This means any library (e.g. Raphael) based on SVG won't work in the default Android browser.  It seems it will be available in 3.0+, based on the second link above (Issue 4695).

[Opera and Firefox for Android do support SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538870/raphaeljs-library-and-smartphones), so that's something you could investigate if it's acceptable to require your Android users to download a browser.

If you are going to package and distribute via PhoneGap, maybe it's possible to build in a WebKit with SVG support there - that's *really* venturing outside my familiar territory, but http://jindroid.com/2010/02/15/svg-support-on-android-webkit/ might be a starting point.

I'm looking into [Dojo's dojox.gfx](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/gfx/) which provides an abstraction across SVG, VML, Silverlight, and Canvas.  Canvas *is* supported by released versions of Android WebKit.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried any of this on any Android emulator or devices yet, just wanted to share what I've read in hopes you don't get too far down an unsupported road :)